# Boot encrypted root to ram

Tags: debian, initramfs

I've tried http://reboot.pro/topic/14547-linux-load-your-root-partition-to-ram-and-boot-it/ on Ubuntu focal with a encrypted root partition as well as Debian 11.5 without encryption and both worked fine.

However, with Debian(I upgraded to testing) and a encrypted partition, it don't work, it just boots as regular with the exception that:

Sometimes mkinitramfs reports:

```
Cryptsetup error, couldn't resolve device none
Cryptsetup couldn't determine root device.
W: couldn't identify type of root file system for fsck hook.
```

Booting the initrd results in /scripts/blocking until it gives up and fails to mount root and starts initramfs terminal

Sometimes mkinitfs only warns about fsck hook in which case it boots as normal and not loaded in ram.

I assume its something wrong with step 4, switching from mounting the unlocked mapped partition to none tmpfa in fstab.

Anyone know what's required for booting a encrypted root into ram with Debian 11.5?

EDIT:

```
Linux owner 5.10.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Fresh install, encrypted, boots as expected into ram

```
Linux owner 5.19.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.19.11-1 (2022-09-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Update to testing. mkinitramfs warns

```
W: couldn't identify type of root file system for fsck hook.
```

And while booting:

```
Warning: fsck not present so skipping root file system
```

And does not load to ram.